# How to scroll the text up automagically when an overflow happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple `div` which fills the header's height but for test purposes, it has a fixed `height` of `400px`.

It looks like this:

[image]

I use a [type-it](https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit) library so it writes the text itself. For now, the `overflow` property is set to `hidden` and it hides the text behind the bottom border.

What I want to achieve is to push the text upwards so it hides behind the top border, not the bottom one (scrolls automatically).

Is this even possible with built-in `CSS` things, or I have to write custom `JS` tools? Thanks for any tips!

Here's the current div's code:

```
.header-code {

    position: absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:400px; /* 100% */
    float: left;

    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    color: yellow;
    border: 1px dotted blue;

    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `overflow: auto` instead of `overflow: hidden` it somewhat will do the same.

Comment: `overflow: auto` enables the scroll and doesn't scroll/push the text itself.

Comment: *enables the scroll...* and also scroll the content to up slightly each time the content overflows the fixed height container.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with type-it, but this may give you something to start with.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.scroll {
  animation: scroll-it 10s linear forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
}

@keyframes scroll-it {
  from { margin-top: 0px; }
  to { margin-top: -600px; }
}
```

```html
<div><span class="scroll">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec placerat iaculis lorem, vitae pharetra orci faucibus eleifend. Praesent urna sapien, consequat nec hendrerit sit amet, convallis in turpis. Integer sollicitudin ullamcorper eros, nec egestas
  odio semper nec. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur consequat lobortis dolor, vel dignissim metus euismod non. Quisque a arcu ut nisi mattis ullamcorper. Nullam et tortor facilisis, imperdiet mi in, varius leo. Nullam
  euismod et neque a laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus dui libero, vehicula vitae turpis ac, facilisis tincidunt quam. Phasellus faucibus purus et mattis blandit. Sed convallis fermentum elit, eget aliquam nisl scelerisque et. Etiam lorem odio,
  ultricies a tortor at, mollis scelerisque est. Nunc mi velit, porttitor non laoreet quis, semper et justo. Praesent dignissim orci sit amet venenatis tempor. Integer hendrerit lorem a aliquam eleifend. Nulla nibh sem, faucibus quis finibus et, volutpat
  ut sapien. Ut consectetur magna tellus, eget condimentum orci facilisis sit amet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed gravida, magna quis sagittis hendrerit, lorem erat consectetur lacus, laoreet congue ligula justo eget tellus. Interdum et malesuada
  fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur aliquet, felis vel pretium consequat, nibh sapien feugiat felis, non finibus erat libero ac lacus. Vivamus molestie augue sagittis varius posuere. Cras nec neque non lectus ultrices lacinia. Nulla nec
  consequat elit, a blandit enim. Pellentesque nec ultricies tortor. Etiam efficitur justo convallis nibh faucibus, in sagittis quam tempus. Curabitur purus ex, venenatis a turpis quis, tincidunt malesuada eros. Aenean at magna sed eros ullamcorper viverra.
  Phasellus vehicula nisl vitae ligula posuere, nec convallis sem vehicula.
</span></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Could be a good use case for the marquee tag! You can also use the `scrollamount` attribute to control the speed at which it will move!

You can read more about this wonderful feature of html4 here: https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm

```css
    
.container {
    background-color: black;
    width:300px;
    height:400px; /* 100% */
    overflow: hidden;
    
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.header {
    width: 94%;
    height: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
    color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<marquee class="header" behaviour="scroll" direction="up">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec placerat iaculis lorem, vitae pharetra orci faucibus eleifend. Praesent urna sapien, consequat nec hendrerit sit amet, convallis in turpis. Integer sollicitudin ullamcorper eros, nec egestas
  odio semper nec. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur consequat lobortis dolor, vel dignissim metus euismod non. Quisque a arcu ut nisi mattis ullamcorper. Nullam et tortor facilisis, imperdiet mi in, varius leo. Nullam
  euismod et neque a laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus dui libero, vehicula vitae turpis ac, facilisis tincidunt quam. Phasellus faucibus purus et mattis blandit. Sed convallis fermentum elit, eget aliquam nisl scelerisque et. Etiam lorem odio,
  ultricies a tortor at, mollis scelerisque est. Nunc mi velit, porttitor non laoreet quis, semper et justo. Praesent dignissim orci sit amet venenatis tempor. Integer hendrerit lorem a aliquam eleifend. Nulla nibh sem, faucibus quis finibus et, volutpat
  ut sapien. Ut consectetur magna tellus, eget condimentum orci facilisis sit amet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed gravida, magna quis sagittis hendrerit, lorem erat consectetur lacus, laoreet congue ligula justo eget tellus. Interdum et malesuada
  fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Curabitur aliquet, felis vel pretium consequat, nibh sapien feugiat felis, non finibus erat libero ac lacus. Vivamus molestie augue sagittis varius posuere. Cras nec neque non lectus ultrices lacinia. Nulla nec
  consequat elit, a blandit enim. Pellentesque nec ultricies tortor. Etiam efficitur justo convallis nibh faucibus, in sagittis quam tempus. Curabitur purus ex, venenatis a turpis quis, tincidunt malesuada eros. Aenean at magna sed eros ullamcorper viverra.
  Phasellus vehicula nisl vitae ligula posuere, nec convallis sem vehicula.
</marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: "Obsolete.
This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it." 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: @Kangouroops oh come on if we cant have fun

Comment: No `<blink>`, no fun ! :D